# How do I get images to rearrange when I resize a CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListCtrl in Report View that displays a series of images (192px X 192px) that a user can click and select.  When the window is resized, I can see more of the images vertically, but not horizontally.  What can I do to reposition the images.  I dynamically generate these images and add the CBitmaps to the image list, if that helps.  They are not icons in the Windows sense

Comment: Can you add images of what it looks like and how you want it to look like? Are you doing custom draw to show these images (because out of the box, listview supports images only in the first column of a report view)?

Comment: Initially the dialog is wide enough to show the images in columns of three.  If I expand it to show more, I can see more vertically, but only three columns of images

Comment: This sounds to me that you don't use report view, but either icon or list view. If this is true, please edit your question to clarify.